# NSDate hebrew date label

Tags: ios, nsdate, hebrew

I make label with the date for today but I need hebrew date for today.

this my code

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[_label setText:dateString];
```

I not build calendar this label with date for today.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the user's current locale is not set for Hebrew, then you need to ensure the date formatter's locale is set for Hebrew,

```
NSLocale *hebrew = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"]; // Hebrew, Israel
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.locale = hebrew;
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[_label setText:dateString];
```

That code will still use the calendar for the user's current locale (such a Gregorian). If you also need the Hebrew calendar, then you need this:

```
NSLocale *hebrew = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"]; // Hebrew, Israel
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSHebrewCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.locale = hebrew;
dataFormat.calendar = calendar;
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[_label setText:dateString];
```

Comment: Just saying thanks :) How come you came across this issue, if you do not speak Hebrew?