# Hebrew Date for today write on label

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I want to show date for today (Hebrew date) with label (not calendar).

How I do it with `NSDate`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

check out these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644451/gregorian-to-hebrew) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109624/nsdate-hebrew-date-label)... May be it will helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Use this to format the date:

```
NSLocale *hebrew = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
format.locale = hebrew;
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *today = [format stringFromDate:now];
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 40, 240, 30)];
lbl.text = today;
NSLog(@"today: %@", today);
```

Comment: what relationship? i didn't get u?